# Flickr has 300MB bandwidth limit for photos, what is the meaning of this?

Tags: images, bandwidth, flickr

300MB bandwidth limit for photos on flickr, how do they calculate that exactly?
Is it: size of image X number of views?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "bandwidth limit" is how much data you can upload each Month to your account. It is based on both pictures and video.  http://www.flickr.com/help/limits/#65  There is no limit to how many times it can be viewed. 
There are many other limitations to the free hosting as usual. http://www.flickr.com/help/forum/en-us/72157627629706032/ 
  Bringing people in to watch thier adds :-) usually isnt one of the issues :-)